# Pandas Dataframe String Column to Concatenated Int

Tags: python, pandas

For simplicity, assume we have a dataframe with a single column that contains string values. I would like to create a second column that contains an integer representing the ASCII value for each character in the string in a concatenated form.  Please see below. Assume column A is what we have, and column B is what we want.

```
Column_A    Column_B
  JJIIV    7474737386
  OOEWW    7979698787
  ZZXSW    9090888387
  QLHMN    8176727778
  WESDFG   876983687071
```

Ok, so looking at the first value in column A, JJIIV, we come up with the result in column B by doing the following 1) Break JJIIV up into 'J','J','I','I','V'. 2)Take the ord() of each character.  ord('J') == 74 etc.  3) concatenate each of the ord values to create a bigint.

So far, i was able to accomplish the following. Im just not sure how to create the extra column in the data frame and 'apply' this logic to each row.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'string_column': ['JJIIV', 'OOEWW', 'ZZXSW', 'QLHMN', 'WESDFG']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['string_column'])

for i in df['string_column']:
    print([ord(c) for c in i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `appply` with a `lambda` to join the ordinal values to create a string of the values:

```
In [114]:    
df['ord'] = df['string_column'].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(ord(e)) for e in x])).astype(np.int64)
df

Out[114]:
  string_column           ord
0         JJIIV    7474737386
1         OOEWW    7979698787
2         ZZXSW    9090888387
3         QLHMN    8176727778
4        WESDFG  876983687071
```

You can cast the `dtype` to `int64` to convert, note that the last entry won't fit in a 32-bit int